# TSQL making a field value into a column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, devexpress

I am trying to do a query on a database to build a chart with the data I pull (using Developer Express). 
And so I have this table that I get back with what I currently have:

[image]

But what I want to do is for the data to pull the field values for all of the instances of MYCOUNT and turn them into their own populated columns like this:

[image]

This is the code for the query:

```
SELECT  
    'Approval Progress' AS ACTIVITY, 
    CASE STATUS 
       WHEN 0 THEN 'NO ACTION' 
       WHEN 1 THEN 'PENDING' 
       WHEN 2 THEN 'APPROVED' 
       WHEN 3 THEN 'REJECTED'
       ELSE 'ERROR' 
    END AS APRV, 
    COUNT(*) AS MYCOUNT,  
    4 AS TOT0, 8 AS TOT1, 3 AS TOT2 
FROM 
    IT_PROJAPPROVEWIP AS IT_PROJAPPROVEWIP_1 
GROUP BY 
    STATUS
```

Thank you!

Comment: Please write code and expected outputs/inputs out, rather than referring to images

Comment: what database server are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one way to do it is use a cross join on each status:

```
SELECT *
FROM
  (SELECT 'Approval Progress' AS ACTIVITY,
          CASE STATUS
              WHEN 0 THEN 'NO ACTION'
              WHEN 1 THEN 'PENDING'
              WHEN 2 THEN 'APPROVED'
              WHEN 3 THEN 'REJECTED'
              ELSE 'ERROR'
          END AS APRV,
          COUNT(*) AS MYCOUNT
   FROM IT_PROJAPPROVEWIP AS IT_PROJAPPROVEWIP_1
   GROUP BY STATUS)a
CROSS JOIN
  (SELECT COUNT(*) AS Tot0
   FROM IT_PROJAPPROVEWIP
   WHERE STATUS = 0 ) b
CROSS JOIN
  (SELECT COUNT(*) AS Tot1
   FROM IT_PROJAPPROVEWIP
   WHERE STATUS = 1 ) c
CROSS JOIN
  (SELECT COUNT(*) AS Tot2
   FROM IT_PROJAPPROVEWIP
   WHERE STATUS = 2 ) d
CROSS JOIN
  (SELECT COUNT(*) AS Tot3
   FROM IT_PROJAPPROVEWIP
   WHERE STATUS = 3 ) e
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for but after about 2 hours of googling I couldn't find anything. Thank you! Can you possibly explain what you did so I can learn how to do this myself?

Comment: Basically, it is calculating count for each status id in sub queries and then joining them to the original data set using Cross Joins. You can read more about cross joins at: http://www.w3resource.com/sql/joins/cross-join.php